# How to disable calls to certain Java packages from Jython

Tags: java, security, jython

I am embedding jython in my Java application. Users will be able to submit and execute some python scripts. I want to make sure that they will not access some vulnerable java packages/classes from those scripts. Another option is to disable java intergation at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possibility to set a custom class loader which jython will use. Code looks like that:

```
final PySystemState state = new PySystemState();
state.setClassLoader(new MyClassLoader());
Py.setSystemState(state);
```

And then in MyClassLoader you can check which java class is being accessed in a script and reject it based on some criteria. This will look something like that

```
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader
{
  @Override
  protected synchronized Class<?> loadClass(final String className, final boolean resolve)
      throws ClassNotFoundException
  {
    if (className.startsWith("secret.class"))
    {
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    return MyClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(className);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the java security manager, that allows you to select what can be accessed or not.